# Нажатие на ветвь через Treeview и вывод в dataGridView - C#

Tags: c#

Добрый день. Есть форма подключенная к базе данных (Access). На Treeview имеются корни и их ветви. Нужно чтобы при нажатии на на определенную ветвь запрашивалась информация с бд и выводилась на dataGridView. К примеру нажимаем на ветвь процессоры, с базы данных берется таблица процессоры и выводится в dataGridView.

Comment: Очень интересное задание. А в чём состоит ваш вопрос?

Comment: Как сделать чтобы при нажатии на определенную ветвь запрашивалась информация с бд и выводилась на dataGridView.

Comment: Ну, подпишитесь на нажатие, запросите результаты из базы данных, и выведите их в нужное место. _Ваш Кэп_. В чём из этого проблема?

Comment: Ну, подпишитесь на нажатие, запросите результаты из базы данных, и выведите их в нужное место.

Покажите программно

Comment: Вам, извините, всю программу написать, или часть работы вы возьмёте на себя?